# Passing ManagedObjectContext to Modal created in Storyboard

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios5, xcode4.2

I have successfully setup my ManagedObjectContext in my AppDelegate.  I have then passed it down to the first ViewController (which is in a NavigationController) via rootViewController followed by viewControllers.objectAtIndex.  I do all of this in Application didFinishLaunching.

This View, however, needs to pass the MOC down in turn to a modal I display.  This modal was created in xcode 4.2 using a Storyboard segue.

How can I access the modal's view controller to set its MOC when it is not created in code?  Is this even possible?  Or do I need to learn how to create/load/display the modal using code?

Comment: Override the prepareForSegue: method